# How to assign EmbeddedDocument to Objet's key in mongoengine

Tags: mongoengine

I have a data structure that looks like this:

`addresses: [
  {
    type: 'home',
    street: 'street',
    city: 'city',
    zipcode: 'zpipcode',
  },
  {
    type: 'work',
    street: 'street',
    city: 'city',
    zipcode: 'zpipcode',
  }
]`

I want to model it like this

`addresses: {
  home: {
    street: 'street',
    city: 'city',
    zipcode: 'zpipcode',
  },
  work: {
    street: 'street',
    city: 'city',
    zipcode: 'zpipcode',
  }
}`

I am using now [GenericEmbeddedDocumentField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.GenericEmbeddedDocumentField) but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Have a look at below code. Remember to import `mongoengine` classes mentioned in the example (Document, MapField, etc..)

**Example of model(s) definition**

```
class Address(EmbeddedDocument):
    street = StringField(required=True, max_length=256)
    zipcode = StringField(required=True, max_length=16)
    city = StringField(required=True, max_length=32)
    country = StringField(default="Poland")

class User(Document):
    email = EmailField(required=True)
    addresses = MapField(field=EmbeddedDocumentField(Address))
```

**Example of usage**

```
user = User(email='test@mail.com')
user.addresses['home'] = Address(street='street', zipcode='zip', city='city')
user.save()
```